# como saber a que boton le dio click? REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

en REACT:
dentro de una tabla tengo dos botones pero no le puedo cambiar el nombre de los eventos, dado la particularidad de mi caso,(ACA NO ESTA COMPLETO ES UN EJEMPLO)

como puedo saber a que boton le di click para luego realizar el evento que quiero? sin cambiar el mismo nombre, lo quiero hacer como un componente controlado

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td> <button  onClick={agregarClick}>Btn Uno </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td> <button  onClick={agregarClick}>Btn dos </button></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
  </table>



//evento OnCLICK
  const agregarClick = () => {
//necesito hacer algo aca que me identifique cual de los dos botones pulse

  };
```

**Edicion: Explico mejor la situacion**

en REACT
en un buscador de canciones lo que hice aca es que me muestre una tabla de resultados si lo que se escribio en el input coincide con algo de la const "canciones"  si coincide me van a aparecer los resultados, y en cada resultado me va a aparecer un boton para agregar esa cancion a otra tabla
tengo un unico  boton  que yo escribo,me va a aparecer cada vez que me saltan mis resultados en la tabla, es un unico boton que escribo, pero luego necesito identificar a cual le di onClick ya que tiene el mismo nombre del evento cada vez que tengo un resultado, necesito saber  a cual boton le di y luego poder mostrar todo el resultado de ese array en una nueva tabla.
aclaro que tambien estoy usando Material ui
gracias, espero la respuesta[image: en la imagen el boton rosado es el que yo escribo una sola vez y me aparece la cantidad de veces necesaria, pero yo solo lo escribi una sola vez con un unico evento, como los distingo de cual es de cual array o resulado?]

```
 const canciones = [
   {
    uuid: "1",
    name: "Clara",
    duration: "3:15",
    artist: {
    name: "NTVG"
    }
  },
  {
    uuid: "2",
    name: "El viejo",
    duration: "3:20",
    artist: {
    name: "La vela"
    }
  },
  {
    uuid: "3",
    name: "Hoy estoy raro",
    duration: "3:00",
    artist: {
    name: "El cuarteto"
      }
   }
    ];

export const CreatorPlayList = (props) => {
  /*states */
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [listaFiltrada, setListaFiltrada] = useState([]);


     /*onChange */
     const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Se ejecuta handleInputChange y actualiza el inputValue");
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    };

   const filtrarCanciones = (cancion) => {
    // Aca filtro las canciones que coinciden con la busqueda
    if (cancion.name.includes(inputValue)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

     /*evento al presionar Tecla enter */
     const handleInputKeyPress = (e) => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
   // primero me quedo con los resultados filtrados
      const resultados = cancion.filter(filtrarCanciones);
      console.log("Tenemos el array con los resultados filtrados:");
     console.log(resultados);

      // despues actualizo el estado con esos resultados
 setListaFiltrada(resultados);
       console.log("Se actualiza el estado de las canciones a mostrar");
      console.log(resultados);
    }
  };

  /*evento OnClick */
  const agregarClick = (e, cancion) => {
   //aca nose bien como hacer que me de ese valor para luego devolver el array y mostrarlo
  };


  return (
<div>
    <Input
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      placeholder="Buscar"
      onKeyPress={handleInputKeyPress}
      value={inputValue}
    />

  <div>
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>Resultados</TableHead><TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Nombre</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Artista</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Album</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Duracion</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Agregar</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {
            // recorro la lista filtrada que tengo en el estado
            listaFiltrada.map((resultados) => (
              <TableRow key={resultados.uuid}>
                {/*Esta es la tabla que debe aparecer si se encuentra un archivo */}
                <TableCell align="center">{resultados.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">
                  {resultados.artist.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{resultados.album}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{resultados.duration}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">
                  {" "}
               {/*este boton me va a aparecer cada vez que me saltan mis resultados en la tabla, es un unico boton que escribo, pero luego necesito identificar a cual le di onClick ya que tiene el mismo nombre del evento, pero cada uno tiene un Array  distinto que lo voy llamando con resultados.name etc */}  
                  <button  onClick={agregarClick}>
                  </button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))
          }
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </div>
</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: aqui no puse states pero claro que lo tiene, y todo esta dentro de una funcion como debe ser

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código completo, para tener una mejor visión de lo que estas intentando hacer, a partir de eso sera mas fácil apoyarte.

Answer (score 2):

Solo agrégale un parámetro a la función para identificar cada botón:

```
const agregarClick = (que_boton_es) => {
    if(que_boton_es == "boton1"){
       //es el boton 1
    }
    else{
       //es el boton 2
    }
};
```

Luego lo llamas asi:

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td> <button  onClick={()=>agregarClick("boton1")}>Btn Uno </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td> <button  onClick={()=>agregarClick("boton2")}>Btn dos </button></td>
</tr>
```

Eso debería de funcionarte. Aunque al ser una tabla quizá el parámetro que deseas enviar el un `ID` o simplemente el `objeto completo`.

### Edicion

En respuesta a la edición, se tiene dos caminos:

Puedes optar por enviar el objeto completo:

```
listaFiltrada.map((resultados) => (
     <TableRow key={resultados.uuid}>
       <TableCell align="center">{resultados.name}</TableCell>
        ...mas codigo
       <TableCell align="center"> 
         <button  onClick={(ev)=>agregarClick(ev,resultados)}>
              </button>
       </TableCell>
     </TableRow>
 ))
```

Y tu funcion ya estaria lista:

```
const agregarClick = (e, cancion) => {
    console.log(cancion);
};
```

Y console.log te mostraría el objeto de la fila que pertenece.

La otra opción sucede lo mismo pero en vez de enviar todo el objeto envias solo el `uuid`:

```
<button  onClick={(ev)=>agregarClick(ev,resultados.uuid)}>
              </button>
```

Y para obtener todo el objeto debemos de buscarlo en tu array `canciones`:

```
const agregarClick = (e, uuid) => {
    let cancion=canciones.find(obj=>obj.uuid==uuid)
    console.log(cancion);
};
```

Espero que con todo esto ya puedas resolver tu problema.
Suerte.

Comment: luego de que me verifica el boton,seria el objeto completo con los datos que quiero que me devuelva

Comment: @Carolain, se clara en tu pregunta. Yo respondí lo que preguntaste. abre otra pregunta o edita esta siendo clara en lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: @Carolain, he editado la respuesta, espero te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de agregar el evento dentro de la misma etiqueta, es recomendable asignarlo cuando se carga el DOM, así evitas repetir fragmentos de código y, además, puedes tener mejor control para depuración y mantenimiento.

Si aún quieres (o necesitas) asignar dentro de la etiqueta, asegúrate de poder enviar como parámetro el evento, por ejemplo:  `onclick="agregarClick(event);"` Así es como se puede acceder al botón y el resto de elementos.

En React sería: `onClick={(e) => agregarClick(e)}` [Referencia](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

```js
const agregarClick = (e) => {
    // Obtener botón que recibió el clic
    let btn = e.target;
    // Fila a la que pertenece el botón
    let tr = btn.closest('tr');
    // TH
    let th = tr.querySelector('th');
    // Celdas [0] tendrá first name y [1] last name
    let tds = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
    // Comprobar
    console.log(th.innerText, tds[0].innerText, tds[1].innerText);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.table button').forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', agregarClick);
    });
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td><button>Btn Uno </button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td><button>Btn dos </button></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas invocar a la función con los parámetros que necesites. La manera de hacer esto es, en lugar de llamar directamente a la función que quieres, ejecutar una función que invoque a la otra.

```
<button onClick={() => agregarClick(resultados.uuid)}>
```

Para recuperar el *evento*, agregas un parámetro en tu *función anónima* y lo envías a tu función:

```
<button onClick={(ev) => agregarClick(ev, resultados.uuid)}>
```

Comment: Si la respuesta a esta pregunta es la misma que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385141/15301), posiblemente deberías marcar la pregunta como duplicada.