# Obtener el valor de dos celdas en una tabla html con un boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buen día tengo el siguiente codigo por el cual voy creando una tabla con valores que voy obteniendo de un select.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btnAgregar').click(function() {
            var _Cero = document.getElementById("cero").value;
            var _Id = document.getElementById("Id").value;
            var _Id_Fracc = document.getElementById("Id_Fraccionamiento").value;
            var _Prototipo = document.getElementById("Prototipo").value;
            var _Concepto = document.getElementById("Concepto").value;
            var _Condominio = document.getElementById("Con").value;
            var _Folio = document.getElementById("Folio").value;
            var i = 1;

            var fila = '<tr id="row' + i++ + '"><td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="id" id="Id[]" name="Id[]">' + _Id + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle; display: none;" id="IdSp[]" name="IdSp[]">' + _Cero + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="Id_Fraccionamiento" id="Fracc[]" name="Fracc[]">' + _Id_Fracc + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;" clas="Prototipo" id="Prot[]" name="Prot[]">' + _Prototipo + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;" class="Concepto" id="Conc[]" name="Conc[]">' + _Concepto + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input class="casas" min="1" value="1" type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)" onKeyUp="pierdeFoco(this)" style="color: black; width: 60px; text-align: center;"></td><td style="vertical-align: middle; display: none;" id="Tipo[]" name="Tipo[]">URBANIZACION-' + _Condominio + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle; display: none;" id="Folio[]" name"Folio[]">' + _Folio + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></td><td " style="vertical-align: middle;"><button id="boton" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></td><td style="vertical-align: middle"><input type="checkbox" id="' + _Id + '" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;"></td></tr>'

            i++;



            $('#agregar #tablita').append(fila);
 });
        });
```

Quiero obtener el valor de 2 celdas de mi tabla mediante un botón, si los obtiene pero si voy creando más de una fila en mi tabla recorre y va obteniendo el valor de la ultima fila mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
jQuery('#agregar').on('click', '#boton', function() {
                $('#agregar #tablita tr').each(function() {
                    var valor1 = $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
                    var valor2 = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
                    alert(valor1);
                    alert(valor2);
                    $('#T_Productos').load('../controller/llenar_tabla2.php?valor1=' + valor1, '&valor2=' + valor2);
                    $("#T_Productos").show();
                });
            });
```

Esta es la tabla que se va creando.

[image: Si quiero obtener el valor de la primera fila, lo que hace es que recorre toda y el valor que me arroja al final es de la ultima fila]

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384909/como-saber-a-que-boton-le-dio-click-react/385021#385021), solo necesitas adaptar un poco.

Comment: Gracias por la información.